# Map an open interval to another one using a logistic curve

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions

Given $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, such that $a < b$ and $m,M \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $m < M$, I would like to map the interval $[a,b]$ to the interval $[m,M]$ using a continuous, monotonically increasing curve shaped like a logistic curve (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function). If $\varphi \, : \, [a,b] \, \longrightarrow \, [m,M]$ is the function I am looking for, I would like to set :

$$ \forall t \in [a,b] \, \varphi(t) = \begin{cases} m & \text{if} \, t=a \\[1mm] ??(t) & \text{if} \, a < t < b \\[1mm] M & \text{if} \, t = b \end{cases} $$

where $??$ is some function which would have the same shape as a logistic function. The function

$$ \ell \, : \, t \in \mathbb{R} \, \mapsto \, m + \frac{M-m}{1+e^{-t}} $$

maps $\mathbb{R}$ to $(m,M)$. So, in order to map $(a,b)$ to $(m,M)$, I could *first* map $(a,b)$ to $(0,1)$ (using an affine function) and *then* map $(0,1)$ to $\mathbb{R}$ (using $y \, \mapsto \, -\ln(\frac{1}{y} - 1)$, for example). But this does not give me the desired function (it actually gives me an affine function in the end).

How shall I address this problem ?

Answer (score 2):

Use a [smoothstep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothstep) such as $S(t) = 3t^2 - 2t^3$, which does a smooth $C^1$ transition from $0$ to $1$ over $[0,1]$.
Then, for $ a < t < b$, use
$$\varphi(t)=m+(M-m)S(\dfrac{t-a}{b-a})$$
This gives you a smooth $C^1$ transition from $m$ to $M$ over $[a,b]$.

For a smooth $C^2$ transition, use $S(t) = 6t^5 - 15t^4 + 10t^3$.

Comment: I didn't know about smoothstep functions ! Thanks.